# Split portions from file to separate file in bash

Tags: bash

From here [Split portion of string in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72390385/split-portion-of-string-in-bash?noredirect=1#comment127883878_72390385), with some code changes,  I managed to achieve the goal.

Now, I want to save the text in separate file.

I tried:

```
awk '/[code]:/{flag=1} flag; /[/code]:/{flag=0}{x="/home/user/split/File"++i".txt";}{print > x;}' /home/user/bigfile.nfo
```

but I got many files with one or no line (empty file with 0 bytes)

How to write all content between `[code]` and `[/code]` to separate file ? As many text found between those tag, as many files should be created, that's my expectation

Where is my mistake in code ?

The bigfile content

```
blavbl
[code]
sdasdasd
asdasd
...
[/code]

line X
line Y
etc
...

[code]
...
test
test
[/code]

blabla

[code]
Single line
[/code]
```

After ran script I get some files with one line instead all text between blocks

I expect to have

*File1.txt*

```
sdasdasd
asdasd
...
```

*File2.txt*

```
...
test
test
```

File3.txt

```
Single line
```

Etc

Comment: Sample file please.

Comment: @markp-fuso don’t know why post is not saved, I updated

Comment: so `File3.txt` will consist of a single blank line, right?

Comment: No, won’t be empty, I forgot to add text, so shouldn’t have ever empty line/content/block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few issues with OP's current code:

- the characters `[`, `]` and `/` have special meaning in `awk` regex patterns; one solution is to escape said characters when looking for them as literal characters
- OP should make sure a file's descriptor is closed once no more output is going to said file (this should keep `awk` from (potentially) crashing due to 'out of file descriptor' errors)
- OP's current patterns include a trailing `:` but no such character exists in OP's sample input (ie, `[code]:` will not match `[code]`)

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
/^\[code\]/   { outfile="/home/user/split/File" ++i ".txt"; next }
/^\[\/code\]/ { close(outfile); outfile=""; next }
outfile       { print > outfile }
' bigfile.nfo
```

**NOTE:** technically `]` (sans the escape `\`) should also work

This generates:

```
$ head File*.txt
==> File1.txt <==
sdasdasd
asdasd
...

==> File2.txt <==
...
test
test

==> File3.txt <==
Single line
```